# Are there any C/C++ library for unwarping images?

Tags: image, unwarp

What I have is a picture taken from the ceiling providing a "radially distorted"/elliptical image. I need to unwarp it and make it a regular rectangular image. How would I do this programmatically using C/C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of applications use [PanoTools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/) for this.  I believe this can also be done with [OpenCV](http://opencv.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll put together something with OpenCV. :)